# SetUnhandledExceptionFilter x64?

Tags: c++

I'm try to SetUnhandledExceptionFilter to handle exception in my process.

1. SetUnhandledExceptionFilter set to my function alloc in memory (VirtualAlloc with PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE).
2. Other function in other memory crash and i want Windows call my exception handle in memory.

it work property in Win32, but when i build it in Win64 it crash but windows no call function set with SetUnhandledExceptionFilter

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

LONG WINAPI OurSetUnhandledExceptionFilter(EXCEPTION_POINTERS * ExceptionInfo)
{
    cout << "Gotcha!" << endl;
    Sleep(-1);
    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
}

void Exception()
{
    SetUnhandledExceptionFilter((LPTOP_LEVEL_EXCEPTION_FILTER)OurSetUnhandledExceptionFilter);
    MessageBox(0, TEXT("Exception"), 0, 0);
}

typedef void (*fException)(void);

DWORD WINAPI xf(LPVOID x)
{
    fException a = (fException)x;
    a();//Call fException

    //Crash
    char *p = 0;
    p[1] = 0;//<-

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    LPVOID nef = VirtualAlloc(0, (INT64)main - (INT64)xf, MEM_COMMIT|MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    memcpy(nef, xf, (INT64)main - (INT64)xf);
    CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)nef, Exception, 0, 0);
    Sleep(-1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `memcpy` does not look fine for this code to be executed. The code is perhaps crashing before even reaching `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` call, or the call provides invalid callback which is never called. This should be easy to see under debugger.

Comment: MSVC doesn't generate position independent code, it generates relocatable code.  The number one problem is that this didn't happen.  What it dies on is that exception handling is implemented very differently in x64, it uses a function table that's searched for the instruction address.  You can't make this work reliably.

Comment: It is also not certain that `main` is actually after `xf` - check the compiled code.

Comment: Those casts to function type are a great way to ask the compiler not to tell you if you've got the signatures wrong.

Comment: i'm build with release and it show 'MessageBox' correctly